# How can I update the email address using the confirmation code in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I use all the functionalities of [dj-rest-auth](https://dj-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to register, log in, confirm the email address, change the password, reset the password and many more. Unfortunately, the library does not support changing the email address. I would like the authenticated user to first enter the account password and the new email address. After the successful process of authentication, I would like to send the user a specially generated confirmation code. Only when he enters it, the old email address will be changed to the new one. As far as I know, there is no such functionality in `dj-rest-auth`. Unfortunately, I also have not found any current solutions or libraries for this purpose anywhere. Did anyone have such a problem and could share his solution here? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Though i don't have any solution for what you want accurately but here is a replace.
You can use django all-auth and some email backend to send an email to the new added email to confirm the new email. In the sent email, there will be a confirmation link and the user has to click that to confirm the new email.
After using django all-auth you only have to add an email backend which will help in sending email. Rest will be maintained by all-auth.
e.g,
In your settings.py you can add an SMTP email backend to send email from your selected gmail account.
Add these lines of code to your settings.py;

```
EMAIL_BACKEND='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'HOST_EMAIL' #HOST_EMAIL is your email from which you want to send email to the user.
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'HOST_PASSWORD' #HOST_PASSWORD is the password of the email you are using as HOST_EMAIL
```

But after doing all these things, to make it work locally, you need to go to your google account which you are using as HOST_EMAIL. Go to **manage google account** >> **security** >> **Turn on less secure apps**. Then you will be able to send email to the user.
**NOTE**: If you have 2-factor authentication turned on for your google account, then these steps will not work. That type of account has some different setup.